# R create variable IF ELSE leads to wrong values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe with:
"serial" the number of households, each one with a variable number of components "head, spouse, parent and child or grandchild" and total number of children in the house "nchild"

I want to create a new variable (in the dput I added an example for clarity: withCM 'living with male child' and withCF). I have tried various combinations but I cannot discriminate on the sex of the child within the same "serial", so that for withCM=1 only when relate=="child"&sex==1, but the 1 would appear on a different row (that of the head, spouse or parent)

```
mydata$withCM<- ifelse(mydata$nchild>0&mydata$relate!="child",1,0)

mydata <- structure(list(serial = c(12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 12346L, 
12346L, 12347L, 12347L, 12347L, 12348L, 12348L, 12348L, 12348L, 
12348L, 12348L, 12348L, 12349L, 12350L, 12350L, 12351L, 12351L, 
12351L, 12352L, 12352L, 12352L, 12352L, 12352L, 12353L, 12354L, 
12354L), age = c(45L, 44L, 13L, 11L, 29L, 28L, 65L, 61L, 35L, 
68L, 61L, 35L, 34L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 62L, 54L, 52L, 67L, 67L, 12L, 
49L, 50L, 28L, 21L, 22L, 70L, 89L, 55L), sex = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), relate = structure(c(4L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("child", 
"childinlaw", "grandchild", "head", "nonrelative", "parent", 
"spouse"), class = "factor"), nchild = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), conhija = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), conhijo = c(1L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("serial", 
 "age", "sex", "relate", "nchild", "conhija", "conhijo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -30L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tabulate the gender, family, and role-within-family as:

```
xtab <- table(mydata$serial, mydata$sex, mydata$relate)
```

And then choose the heads of the families (or, in the commented line, anyone who has the specific relationship), and alter their tallies as follows:

```
mydata$sex1 <- 0
mydata$sex2 <- 0
ind <- mydata$relate=="head"
#ind <- mydata$relate %in% c("head","spouse","parent")
mydata$sex1[ind] <- xtab[as.character(mydata$serial[ind]), "1", "child"]
mydata$sex2[ind] <- xtab[as.character(mydata$serial[ind]), "2", "child"]
```

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks for the suggestion. Basically my new variable should be identical to "conhijo" if sex of child=1 and equal to "conhija" if sex of the child=2 but only for those whose nchild>0, so e.g. CONHIJO==1 IF NCHILD>0 AND SEX of child in the same SERIAL ==1. I have tried your way but I'm still missing something

Comment: So taking serial=12345 as an example - there are both sex=2 and sex=1 children, so should the new variable equal conhijo or conhija in this case (and which row should we set the value of this variable? everywhere where nchild!=0?)

Comment: changed to this `mydata$ind <- mydata$nchild>0` as it gives me the places where I want to put 1 if the sex of the child in serial is 1 and 0 otherwise

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify.  Have you shown us conhija and conhijo as examples of variables you are asking us to recreate; or are they existing variables that we should use in some further calculation?

Comment: Because, if you're asking us to recreate conhija, then I do that by setting `ind` as in your comment, and also changing the `sex1` line by wrapping the right hand side of the assignment in `ifelse(xtab[....]>0, 1,0)`

Comment: It works! yes, exactly as you said, `conhijo` and `conjiha` are the mock variables I want to create

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to split into families, then test if they are an adult, and there is at least one male child in the unit.

```
lives_with_boy <- function(serial)
{
  unit <- mydata[mydata$serial==serial,]
  as.character(unit$relate) %in% c("head","spouse","parent") & any(unit$relate == "child" & unit$sex==1)
}

mydata$withCM <- unlist(lapply(unique(mydata$serial),lives_with_boy ))
```